# Mysql subquery help

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a table which had two types of records - update and end (EventType - Column).

The Update record has the PID and webpage details where as the end record has the volume (upload and download) and PID detail (no web page detail:(). The common field for the both of the record types are PID.

Now from the table, I need to get the SUM(ULVolume+DLVolume) for all of the websites 
i.e
- get sum(ULVo+DLVol) of each (get PID of each (get distinct websites))

At the end, this is what i am looking for from one single query.Need some help here.
P.S. The database is huge >10G and query which takes less time wud be preferred.

Expected Output

```
Website     Sum(ULVolume+DLVolume)
apple.com   112343XXXXX
google.com  121232XXXXX
```

Update Record:

```
+-----------------+--------+---------------+----------+----------+
| PID             | Event  | Web           | ULVolume | DLVolume |
+-----------------+--------+---------------+----------+----------+
| 199710687818416 | update | kaspersky.com |          |          |
| 199710687818417 | update | google.com    |          |          |
| 199710687818418 | update | yahoo.com     |          |          |
+-----------------+--------+---------------+----------+----------+
```

End Record:

```
+-----------------+-------+------+----------+----------+
| PID             | Event | Web  | ULVolume | DLVolume |
+-----------------+-------+------+----------+----------+
| 199710687818416 | end   |      |     5187 |   309683 |
+-----------------+-------+------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Can there be more than one update per PID?

Comment: Yes...One PID can have multiple update records

Comment: It's pretty hard to know what you want. Your question is very vague. Some more sample data would help. In fact, sample data and sample output is the *best* way to ask a question

Comment: A list of technologies is not a good question title (and we already know that you want "help"). Please improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    u.website,
    sum(e.ULVolume + e. DLVolume) as volume
from mytable e
left join mytable u on u.PID = e.PID and u.event ='update'
where e.Event = 'end'
group by 1;
```

Comment: No problem. **Note:** I added the `group by` which was previously missing.

Comment: When running the above query on a table having 2 million records,mysql process seem to hog the CPU with 100% utilization. Have been waiting for more than 15 mins and still the query is running.... 
any performance tweaks which can improve this?