# Query hogs 100% CPU and didn't complete even after 6 hrs

Tags: mysql, performance, tweak

For the problem below, I got the query working. But when I am running the above query on a table having 2 million records, the MySQL process seems to hog the CPU with 100% utilization. I have been waiting for more than 15 minutes and still the query is running.  Are there any performance tweaks which can improve this?

[Mysql subquery help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712847/mysql-subquery-help)

```
select
    u.website,
    sum(e.ULVolume + e.DLVolume) as volume
from mytable e
left join mytable u on u.PID = e.PID and u.event ='update'
where e.Event = 'end'
group by 1;
```

System is running with Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X3430  @ 2.40GHz CentOS 5.6 with 8GB of RAM.

## Update with EXPLAIN output:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1   select_type: SIMPLE
        table: e
         type: ALL possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2858631
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1   select_type: SIMPLE
        table: u
         type: ALL possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2858631
        Extra: 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What indices do you have in your tables? Try prepending an [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html) so see if indices are actually used.

Comment: Pls forgive me... I am not an expert @ mysql and i am not sure about the indicies.... have appended the output of EXPLAIN in the question itself.

Comment: That's hard to read. In MySQL CLI, enter the query with a terminating literal `\G`, like `EXPLAIN SELECT … \G`.

Comment: You do not have indices. Create them. The columns in question are the ones suggested by Blindy: `u.pid`, `u.event`, `e.Event`.

Comment: Updated the question section with the explain output

Comment: Thanks Shi and Blindy.... After creating indices it works in seconds now...! Thanks once again!!!

Answer (score 3):

The obvious one is: create indices on `mytable.PID` *and* `mytable.event`.

Comment: `GROUP BY 1` groups by `u.website`, the first field in the list. Guess it is needed for the `SUM()`.

Comment: `GROUP BY 1` means 'group by the first column in the select-list', not 'group by the value 1'.  It is an obsolescent feature of SQL.  In this example, `GROUP BY u.website` would be better notation.